# I'm trying to figure out why there is "to be" instead of "is" in the sentence

Tags: grammar, modal-verbs

Why do I have to put "to be" instead of "is" or "will be" in the sentence below. Could you explain what grammar rule this is? What I should seek in Google?

> I didn't expect the graphics of the video game **to be** detailed.

I mean graphics turned out better then I thought.

Comment: **didn't expected** is ungrammatical.   When forming a negated past tense using **did** + **not**, the form of the verb is the unmarked/bare infinitive, here **expect**.  *I did not expect...*

Comment: thx. I've fixed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we use the verb **expect** to refer to a future probability, and the meaning of the verb **expect** is "to anticipate", the pattern is

expect  something|someone  **will** + {bare infinitive}

or

expect something|someone + {marked infinitive}

or

expect something|someone **to be** {adjective phrase}

or

expect something|someone **will be** {adjective phrase}

> I expect the app will crash.
>
> I expect the app to crash.
>
> I expect the app to be buggy.
>
> I expect the app will be buggy.

When  speaking of an anticipated future possibility in the past, the pattern with **will** is not used.

> I expected the app to crash.
>
> I did not expect the app to crash.
>
> I expected the app to be buggy.
>
> I did not expect the app to be buggy.

But you can use **would** instead of **will**:

> I expected the app would be buggy.

NOTE: A relatively small subset of native speakers, not all of them,  use the verb **expect** also to mean "believe" or "suspect" and for these speakers the following non-standard pattern is available:

expect something|someone **is|was** {adjective phrase}

> What is wrong with the dog? It's just lying there.
>   -- I expect it is sick.

or past tense:

> What was wrong with the dog? It was just lying there.
>   -- I expect it was sick.